# Split Jupyter Notebook in different .py files

Tags: python, sections

So I have a Jupyter Notebook with the following sections (headers):

```
0.Description
1.General Configuration
2.RAW
3.Index
```

These sections contain cells of code that perform several operations.
What I want now is to run SPECIFIC sections of this notebook exporting them as .py files.
For example, extract the parts of the jupyter that belong to sections 0,1,2 and export them to a python file. Or in another case maybe sections 0,1,3.
Is that possible? Can I split jupyter notebook according to the table of contents and retrieve these specific parts of the code?

Any ideas would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: The notebook format is just JSON: https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest